# blackberry alert ringtone via my application

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I want to access the default ringtone of the BlackBerry device via code.
My code is given below, and it plays sound, but I want to alert the ring tone, like an incoming call.  What should I do?

`net.rim.device.api.system.Alert.startAudio(tune1, VOLUME);`

Comment: i used net.rim.device.api.system.Alert.startBuzzer(tune1, VOLUME); also. But its same as the previous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set the notification up to do that, but you can make is so that your user can set a system alert to play which ever ring tone s/he wants. Have a look at my article on [Using the BlackBerry Notifications Manager](http://www.hrbuckley.net/2011/03/using-blackberry-notifications-manager.html).